# Check for more than one key value pair in JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data formatted with multiple products which each have multiple variants and has data showing if the variant is available as well as the size of the variant.

```
 "products":[  
    {  
     "variants":[  
        {  
          "available":true,
          "selectedOptions":[  
             {  
                "name":"Size",
                "value":"M"
             }
          ]
        },
        {  
          "available":true,
          "selectedOptions":[  
             {  
                "name":"Size",
                "value":"L"
             }
          ]
        }          
      ]
    },
    {  
     "variants":[
        {  
          "available":true,
          "selectedOptions":[  
             {  
                "name":"Size",
                "value":"S"
             }
          ]
        },     
        {  
          "available":false,
          "selectedOptions":[  
             {  
                "name":"Size",
                "value":"L"
             }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

I want to traverse the JSON data and tell if the size of the product variant is large ("value":"L") and if the product is available ("available":true). I'm able to check for one or the other but I'm not sure how to check both at the same time. This is what I have so far:

```
o = products;    
function traverse(o) {
  for (var i in o) {
    if(o[i] == true){
      console.log([i,o[i]]);
    }
    if(o[i] == 'L'){
      console.log([i,o[i]]);
    }
    if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
      traverse(o[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(o);
traverse(o);  
}
```

Comment: Well, don't use the `process` function; just look for what you want in the `traverse` function. Seems like you've overengineered yourself into making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Why don't you simply use nested `Array.prototype.filter()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach to loop over the possible variants per product and identify the target according to availability and size.

This approach uses the function `find` and `forEach` for traversing the Object.

The function `find` looks for a `selectedOption` with size `L` and the nested `forEach` to check the availability.

```js
var obj = {  "products": [{      "variants": [{          "available": true,          "selectedOptions": [{            "name": "Size",            "value": "M"          }]        },        {          "available": true,          "selectedOptions": [{            "name": "Size",            "value": "L"          }]        }      ]    },    {      "variants": [{          "available": true,          "selectedOptions": [{            "name": "Size",            "value": "S"          }]        },        {          "available": false,          "selectedOptions": [{            "name": "Size",            "value": "L"          }]        }      ]    }  ]};

obj.products.forEach((p, i) => {
  p.variants.forEach((v) => {
    if (v.available) {
      var found = v.selectedOptions.find((s) => s.value === 'L');
      if (found) {
        console.log(`Found a product at index '${i}' with variant ['${v.available}' | '${found.value}']`);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```